# Colors of a smoke flow object reflect on another smoke flow object

Tags: modeling, animation

I am more or less a beginner with blender and I modelled and animated a logo which is consisting of smoke and will be blown away by wind.
The question: Why does the white and green color show up on the black frame around the two objects? 
All three (white, green, and black) are defined as smoke flow objects inside a smoke domain.
Best regards, Wolfgang[image: Green and white is reflecting on the frame]

Comment: This looks like refraction. Do you have glass materials here ?

Comment: All the Parts are smoke flow objects (Volume material, no density, as described in many tutorials for smoke modeling).